# angular upgrade from 4 to 5 ngOutletContext

Tags: angular, angular5

I am currently using angular 4.3.4 with maven build. no angular-cli.
I was able to find new set of libraries and version (package.json) from angular.io

just with updated 5.x angular libraries when i ran applicatoin i am getting lot of errors but first error is as following

```
ngOutletContext since it isn't a known property of ng-template.
```

are there any other changes ? help is appreicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been renamed to `ngTemplateOutletContext`.

You can find a full list of breaking changes in the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#500-pentagonal-donut-2017-11-01).